# Reading a file in Matlab, columns are separated with multiple space

Tags: matlab, readfile

I'm trying to load a file, file columns separated with space, but there are different number of space 
between columns. because of this while i'm reading, I'm getting error
Example Data :

```
AAT_ECOLI   0.49  0.29  0.48  0.50  0.56  0.24  0.35   cp
ACEA_ECOLI  0.07  0.40  0.48  0.50  0.54  0.35  0.44   cp
ACEK_ECOLI  0.56  0.40  0.48  0.50  0.49  0.37  0.46   cp
ACKA_ECOLI  0.59  0.49  0.48  0.50  0.52  0.45  0.36   cp
```

you can see that, between first column and second there 3 space, and 2nd column and 3th column there are two space.

can you suggest a me function which work ?

Original data file :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_XEmkrWR-hCMXVySVI2bU5waGs/view?usp=sharing
Thank you

Comment: Did you try 'importdata'? It seems to work for me.

Comment: It is setting all data in one cell :S. i couldn't separate data

Comment: alright I posted an answer I hope that's what you had in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Long version of my comment:

Using `importdata` seems to work fine; The trick you are looking for (I think :) is to concatenate all the data into one big cell and you are good to go;

Code:

```
Data = importdata('ecoli.data');
AllData = vertcat(Data{:})
```

First few rows:

```
AllData =

AAT_ECOLI   0.49  0.29  0.48  0.50  0.56  0.24  0.35   cp
ACEA_ECOLI  0.07  0.40  0.48  0.50  0.54  0.35  0.44   cp
ACEK_ECOLI  0.56  0.40  0.48  0.50  0.49  0.37  0.46   cp
ACKA_ECOLI  0.59  0.49  0.48  0.50  0.52  0.45  0.36   cp
ADI_ECOLI   0.23  0.32  0.48  0.50  0.55  0.25  0.35   cp
```

Then you can convert the numbers into actual digits, since they are currently characters. Is this what you meant?

Comment: But this is char matrix, i couldn't parse or split it? maybe there is another way to handle it?

Comment: mhh I don't know then sorry. You could use a loop to go through each row and convert the char into digits?